Laptop stays in Airplane Mode On
I just installed Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 on an HP Pavilion g7.
My problem is that Airplane Mode is on and does not respond to the hardware key.
Ubuntu does recognize the Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7260.
~# dmesg | grep iwl

[    5.515735] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x0, cnv-id 0x0 wfpm id 0x0

[    5.515759] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: PCI dev 08b1/4070, rev=0x144, rfid=0xd55555d5

[    5.542536] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

[    6.437475] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144

[    6.444890] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)

[    6.444920] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.

[    6.462121] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: base HW address: 00:16:6f:f7:f6:e3, OTP minor version: 0x0

[    6.480802] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'

[    6.841153] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0 wlp7s0: renamed from wlan0

Does anyone know how I can get Wifi running?

Looks like rfkill blocks it. Can you add rfkill --output-all output.

Found an article where it says to block pin 20 on the Intel AC 7260 Wi-Fi adapter (PCI Express). This did the trick, I am now able to use Wi-Fi.
